# Iterating over Java collections in Scala

Tags: java, scala, collections, scala-java-interop

I'm writing some Scala code which uses the [Apache POI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI) API. I would like to iterate over the rows contained in the `java.util.Iterator` that I get from the Sheet class. I would like to use the iterator in a `for each` style loop, so I have been trying to convert it to a native Scala collection but will no luck.

I have looked at the Scala wrapper classes/traits, but I can not see how to use them correctly. How do I iterate over a Java collection in Scala without using the verbose `while(hasNext()) getNext()` style of loop?

Here's the code I wrote based on the correct answer:

```
class IteratorWrapper[A](iter:java.util.Iterator[A])
{
    def foreach(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
        while(iter.hasNext){
          f(iter.next)
        }
    }
}

object SpreadsheetParser extends Application
{
    implicit def iteratorToWrapper[T](iter:java.util.Iterator[T]):IteratorWrapper[T] = new IteratorWrapper[T](iter)

    override def main(args:Array[String]):Unit =
    {
        val ios = new FileInputStream("assets/data.xls")
        val workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(ios)
        var sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)
        var rows = sheet.rowIterator()

        for (val row <- rows){
            println(row)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to include the line "for (val row <- rows){" without the parser thinking the '<' character is an XML closing tag? The backticks do not work

Comment: You should be able to convert to IteratirWrapper implicitly, saving you a fair bit of syntax. Google for implicit conversions in Scala.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a wrapper class (`scala.collection.jcl.MutableIterator.Wrapper`). So if you define

```
implicit def javaIteratorToScalaIterator[A](it : java.util.Iterator[A]) = new Wrapper(it)
```

then it will act as a sub class of the Scala iterator so you can do `foreach`.

Comment: It should read:
    scala.collection.jcl.MutableIterator.Wrapper

Comment: This answer is obsolete in Scala 2.8; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708990/whats-the-new-way-to-iterate-over-a-java-map-in-scala-2-8-0

Answer (score 259):

As of Scala 2.8, all you have to do is to import the JavaConversions object, which already declares the appropriate conversions.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

This won't work in previous versions though.

Answer (score 36):

**Edit**: Scala 2.13.0 deprecates `scala.collection.JavaConverters`, so since 2.13.0 you need to use `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`.

Scala 2.12.0 deprecates `scala.collection.JavaConversions`, so since 2.12.0 one way of doing this would be something like:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

// ...

for(k <- javaCollection.asScala) {
    // ...
}
```

(notice the import, new is JavaConverters, deprecated is JavaConversions)

Comment: I was looking for "toScala" ^_^!

Answer (score 15):

The correct answer here is to define an implicit conversion from Java's `Iterator` to some custom type. This type should implement a `foreach` method which delegates to the underlying `Iterator`. This will allow you to use a Scala `for`-loop with any Java `Iterator`.

Answer (score 9):

For Scala 2.10:

```
// Feature warning if you don't enable implicit conversions...
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.collection.convert.WrapAsScala.enumerationAsScalaIterator
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are iterating through a large dataset, then you probably don't want to load whole collection into memory with `.asScala` implicit conversion. In this case, a handy way approach is to implement `scala.collection.Iterator` trait

```
import java.util.{Iterator => JIterator}

def scalaIterator[T](it: JIterator[T]) = new Iterator[T] {
  override def hasNext = it.hasNext
  override def next() = it.next()
} 

val jIterator: Iterator[String] = ... // iterating over a large dataset
scalaIterator(jIterator).take(2).map(_.length).foreach(println)  // only first 2 elements are loaded to memory
```

It has similar concept but less verbose IMO :)

Answer (score 5):

You could convert the Java collection to an array and use that:

```
val array = java.util.Arrays.asList("one","two","three").toArray
array.foreach(println)
```

Or go on and convert the array to a Scala list:

```
val list = List.fromArray(array)
```

Answer (score 5):

With Scala 2.10.4+ (and possibly earlier) it is possible to implicitly convert java.util.Iterator[A] to scala.collection.Iterator[A] by importing scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaIterator. Here is an example:

```
object SpreadSheetParser2 extends App {

  import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
  import java.io.FileInputStream
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaIterator

  val ios = new FileInputStream("data.xls")
  val workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(ios)
  var sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)
  val rows = sheet.rowIterator()

  for (row <- rows) {
    val cells = row.cellIterator()
    for (cell <- cells) {
      print(cell + ",")
    }
    println
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to avoid the implicits in *scala.collection.JavaConversions* you can use **scala.collection.JavaConverters** to convert explicitly.

```
scala> val l = new java.util.LinkedList[Int]()
l: java.util.LinkedList[Int] = []

scala> (1 to 10).foreach(l.add(_))

scala> val i = l.iterator
i: java.util.Iterator[Int] = java.util.LinkedList$ListItr@11eadcba

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> i.asScala.mkString
res10: String = 12345678910
```

Note the use of the `asScala` method to convert the Java `Iterator` to a Scala `Iterator`.

The JavaConverters have been available since Scala 2.8.1.

Comment: I used `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`  and then  `javaList.iterator().asScala`  from your example and it worked