# What's the new way to iterate over a Java Map in Scala 2.8.0?

Tags: scala, language-features, scala-2.8

How does `scala.collection.JavaConversions` supercede the answers given in Stack Overflow question *[Iterating over Java collections in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741)* (it doesn't work because the "jcl" package is gone) and in *[Iterating over Map with Scala](http://www.eishay.com/2009/05/iterating-over-map-with-scala.html)* (it doesn't work for me in a complicated test which I'll try to boil down and post here later).

The latter is actually a Scala Map question, but I think I need to know both answers in order to iterate over a `java.util.Map`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In 2.8, you import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` and use as a Scala map.  Here's an example (in 2.8.0.RC1):

```
scala> val jmap:java.util.Map[String,String] = new java.util.HashMap[String,String]  
jmap: java.util.Map[String,String] = {}

scala> jmap.put("Hi","there")
res0: String = null

scala> jmap.put("So","long")
res1: String = null

scala> jmap.put("Never","mind")
res2: String = null

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> jmap.foreach(kv => println(kv._1 + " -> " + kv._2))
Hi -> there
Never -> mind
So -> long

scala> jmap.keys.map(_.toUpperCase).foreach(println)
HI
NEVER
SO
```

If you specifically want a Scala iterator, use `jmap.iterator` (after the conversions import).

Comment: Wow, this is a great, painless solution!

Comment: There should be a way without converting to scala map, right ? It will better if we are iterating over java map in a loop, it will avoid unnecessary object creation. Getting " found   : (String, String) => Unit
 required: java.util.function.BiConsumer[_ >: String, _ >: String]" error.

Comment: @ZxcvMnb - These days you should use `JavaConverters` and explicitly change them; with Java 8's addition of a `foreach` method, you can't use implicit conversion any more for `foreach`.