# Excel writer Module for Play Framework v2.x

Tags: excel, scala, playframework

How it would be possible to generate Excell reports from Play Framework v2.x(Scala). I found there's a [Play-Excel](https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-excel) module but it supports PlayFramework v1.0. Is there anything suitable for v2.x?

Comment: I guess you will have to use Apche Poi and write your own, Or you can use `dynamicreports` ( http://www.dynamicreports.org ) and export to xls - http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/excelreport1

Comment: thanks for reply! What do I have to write on my own using Apache Poi?

Comment: Poi provides low level API to create your excel documents with great flexibility and control, but you can also look at `dynamicreports` option.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I choose to use [Spoiwo. Scala Wrapper for Apache POI](https://github.com/norbert-radyk/spoiwo). It has a neat starting guide. However, doesn't have an example with PlayFramework.

Here's my quick and dirty hack to generate simple report from case class.

```
def generateReportXLSX(waybillId: Long) = Action{ implicit request =>

    val headerStyle =
      CellStyle(fillPattern = CellFill.Solid, fillForegroundColor = Color.DarkGrey, fillBackgroundColor = Color.AquaMarine, font = Font(bold = true))

    val listItems: List[Item] = Items.findByWaybillId(waybillId)

    val listRows = listItems.map{ item =>
      Row().withCellValues(item.id.getOrElse(1), item.itemCode, item.senderName.getOrElse(""))
    }

    val gettingStartedSheet = Sheet(name = "Накладная ")
      .withRows(listRows)
      .withColumns(
        Column(index = 0, style = CellStyle(font = Font(bold = true)), autoSized = true)
      )

    gettingStartedSheet.saveAsXlsx("/home/user/dumps/"+waybillId+".xlsx")

    Ok.sendFile(new File(("/home/user/dumps/"+waybillId+".xlsx")))

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer

Comment: You can add onClose trigger to delete temporary files.    `def onClose(): Unit = new File(tmpFile).delete()   Ok.sendFile(new File(tmpFile), onClose = onClose)`