# Scala Collection in JSF

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have developed a Scala and JSF application for learning purpose. In this app I have to convert all my Scala collection objects to Java cllectios before it get rendered in JSF. Is there any easy way this can be achived with something like ScalaElResolver, if yes anybody have a sample code for ScalaElResolver.
Thanks in Advance
Philip

Comment: I don't know JSF, but isn't [standart conversion methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741/iterating-over-java-collections-in-scala) are not applicable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is based on [ScalaElResolver](https://gist.github.com/werpu/1069529) by Werner Punz. 
I have stripped it down, so it just handles the conversion from a Scala `Iterable` to a `java.lang.Iterable`:

```
class SimpleScalaElResolver extends ELResolver {
  override def getValue(elContext: ELContext, base: AnyRef, 
                        prop: AnyRef): AnyRef = {
    println(s"SimpleElResolver: getValue: Entering: $base.$prop")
    if (base == null) {
      null
    } else {
      val method = base.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(prop.toString)
      if (method != null) {
        val res = method.invoke(base)
        if (res.isInstanceOf[Iterable[_]]) {
          val iter = res.asInstanceOf[Iterable[_]]
          println("getValue: Wrapping as Java iterable")
          elContext.setPropertyResolved(true)
          JavaConversions.asJavaIterable(iter)
        } else {
          null
        }
      } else {
        null
      }
    }
  }
```

This is sufficient to get it running using `sbt` and its web plugin (which uses `jetty` under the hood), even if all other methods remained "not yet implemented", like this:

```
override def getCommonPropertyType(elContext: ELContext, o: AnyRef): Class[_] = {
  ???
}
```

The other methods were not called in my case.

I've tested it only from within a `.jspx`; as far as I know this should work with `JSF` as well.

---

Example: If you have a class

```
class Model(val list: List[Int])
```

and in your controller

```
val model = new Model(List(1))

httpRequest.setAttribute("model", model)
```

you can access the instance in EL

```
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="i" items="${ model.list }">
                <li>
                    <c:out value="${ i }"/>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
```

so the property name in EL exactly matches the name of the `val` in your model class. Otherwise you get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: HiThanks you very much for the quick response.

Comment: I am getting an exception                                                                 WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.externalContext()
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1956)
 at com.philipj.scala.web.booking.ScalaElResolver.getValue(ScalaElResolver.scala:18)
 at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
 at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.

Comment: @PhilipJ I have added an example to the answer. Please check if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just opened a scalaelresolver project on github, https://github.com/werpu/scalaelresolver the resolver does besides resolving scala properties also the collection conversions. An example is included.

Comment: Includes ownership disclosure, hence not spam.