# Apache collections UnmodifiableSet to scala immutable Set

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop, apache-commons-collection

What should I do when I get this?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.collections.set.UnmodifiableSet 
    cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Set
```

Comment: You should find a corresponding line in the source code and get rid of `asInstanceOf` or `java` cast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over Java collections in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741/iterating-over-java-collections-in-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast between them, but you should be able to use the scala.collection.JavaConverters to convert java.util.Set (UnmodifiableSet implements this) => mutable.Set, and then call .toSet to convert to an immutable.Set, eg:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.set.UnmodifiableSet
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val u = new UnmodifiableSet()
val s = u.asScala.toSet
println(s)
```

see:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters

(Alternatively use JavaConversions and the asScala can happen implicitly - explicit generally better)